# MS Access - Why is the Totals button on the ribbon in my report greyed out?

Tags: ms-access

I have a report that takes it's information from a query. The query sums up 2 fields.

I now want to show the *average* of these summed rows on the report for the end user, but the `Totals` button is greyed out at the top ribbon.

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkJln.jpg

**Query**

```
SumMatlPlan      SumMatlAct
5561.649          5530.60309
4271.921775       4207.94922
4858.452          4892.5898
3765.3003         3840.9317
```

**Report**

```
     "Material Planned Cost"      "Material Actual Cost"
          5561.649                     5530.60309
          4271.921775                  4207.94922
          4858.452                     4892.5898
          3765.3003                    3840.9317
Average: [this is where I want to show the average for both columns]
```

Comment: Is your report built off of a Crosstab query?

Comment: @Newd No, it's not. It's just a regular Select query. But I was reading somewhere that the button is greyed out because my report is based off a web database? But then what is another way to show the averages at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to go to Layout View and select the data in the column. This opened up a Totals button at the top ribbon. The difference was that I was trying to do this in Design View when it was actually in Layout View.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the format for the field in the table is set to some kind of number.

If it is and the total still doesn't show up you can try doing it manually by adding an unbound textbox and then adding something like:

=Sum(MaterialActualCost)/count(IDnumber)

to the control.

Answer (score 1):

Try another method. Put a new textbox in either the report footer or page footer. And add this to its source in order to get the total: =Sum([FieldName])

Comment: To get average you can add another textbox, make it: count([fieldname]).. then make both these fields invisible. Add another unbound textbox and set its control to be textbox1/textbox2

Comment: I'm trying your method out but the resulting sum just shows "#Error" and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, the aforementioned method of adding `=Sum([fieldName])` to text box can be used. It will bypass an issue where the options within Totals are unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same issue. Realized I had my SUM function in the Page Footer and not the Report Footer. Moving to Report Footer fixed the problem.